# React vertical Nested List open and close sub List

Tags: reactjs

i have a react.js component in which i am displaying states and under i am displaying districts. To display this list it's working fine. The problem i want when i press any sates only that particular state sublist should display not all states sublist.

```
import React,{useState} from "react"
  Const [open,,setOpen]=useState(false);
   

//Wrapper component
 </div>
    {states.map((city, index) => {
      return <StateList state={state} key={index} />;
    })}
  </div>

//state component


<div onClick={()=>setOpen(!open)}>
     
          <span >{state.name}</span>

          <svg
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            className={`
                    ${open ? "rotate-180" : ""}
                  `}
          >
      
          </svg>
        </h2>

       {open && <AreaList area={city} />}
      </div>
```

//district component

```
 const AreaList = ({ state }) => {
    return state.districts.map((district) => (
      <li>
       
         
            
          
          <span className="ml-2 text-outer-space">
            {district.name}
          </span>
       
      </li>
    ));
```

};

[image]

Comment: We need to see a more complete view of the code, particularly the `setOpenState` and where its coming from.

Comment: Your code still is still significantly reduced and not coherent as its copy-pasted together. Sorry, but may I suggest you copy paste the full file or at least the full component definitions? It looks like the open state is in the wrong place on first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution (without styles):

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-elbakyan-wmdfgr?file=/src/App.js:0-898)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Fujairah",
    districts: [
      { name: "Al Buthna" },
      { name: "Al Bedia" },
      { name: "Town Center" },
      { name: "Wadi Al Sedr" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Abu Dhabi",
    districts: [{ name: "Al Aman" }, { name: "Al Bahya" }]
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((city) => {
        return <City key={city.name} city={city} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const City = ({ city }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
      <h2>
        <span>{city.name}</span>
      </h2>
      {open && <DistrictList city={city} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const DistrictList = ({ city }) => {
  return city.districts.map((district) => (
    <li key={district.name}>
      <span>{district.name}</span>
    </li>
  ));
};

export default App;
```